# PowerApps Search Function - No Dataverse Tables?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I keep running into weird little issues with PowerApps, and the latest is really annyoing.

I set up a search function to search a Dataverse table, based on what's typed into an input box. This filters a gallery component (it's basically a directory search). This was working fine when I tried using a SQL Server table as the data source. Since it turns out that is a "premium connector" and will cost a gajillion dollars to use in my organization, I instead set up a dataflow to push data to a dataverse table. That all works fine, but when I use the dataverse table instead of the SQL Server table, the Search function spits out errors, saying that it's the wrong data type. Why isn't a dataverse "table" a table that Search can use? I tried using Filter, but that only returned results when one letter was typed into the input field. Any more, and no results were displayed.

Format of the Search (used in the Items property of the gallery; I also tried it with just one field name to search on and same result):

```
Search(EmployeeDirectory, InputSearch.Text, "Last_Name", "First_Name", "Dept")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure that Dataverse is **not** a premium connector in your org! There has been a lot of changes in regard to Dataverse. IIRC, Dataverse **is** a premium connector. Datavers for Teams, is not. I'm unsure of the difference.

Comment: Yeah - hating this big time. In PowerApps, Dataverse doesn't show as a premium connector (doesn't have the little diamond next to the connector), but when I look at the app details of the PowerApp, it says it's using a premium connector. Lame.